# How do I use Spring Mongo to group two fields and get a array of one fields based on the other?

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let me give a example here:

Two entries in the collection Author:

```
{
"name" : "Joe"
"Book" : "A"
},
{
"name" : "Joe"
"Book" : "B"
}
```

Now, if I use the aggregation function in Mongo via spring mongo, basically just to grab the books with name Joe, it could be coded like:

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(Map.class, group("name", "Book"));

AggregationResults<Map> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "Author",
                Map.class);
```

Obviously I could get two Maps this way, one has entry `{"name":"Joe", "Book": A}`, the other has `{"name" : "Joe", "Book" : "B"}`

But what if I want get ONLY one result back, with one entry :

```
{"name" : Joe, "Books" : ["A", "B"]}?
```

I'm not sure if it is reachable just using one query. It certainly could be achieved by multiple steps, which I'd hate to do..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) operator in your [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) pipeline. This will return an array of all unique values `["A", "B"]` that results from applying the [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) expression to each document in a group of documents that share the same group by key `"name"`. So in mongo shell you have

```
db.author.aggregate([
    { $group: {
        _id: '$name',
        Books: { $addToSet: '$Book' }
    } }
]);
```

which brings back the desired result

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "Joe",
            "Books" : [ "B", "A" ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

The equivalent Spring aggregation:

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(Map.class, group("name").addToSet("Book").as("Books"));

AggregationResults<Map> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "Author", Map.class);
```

Comment: Can I make the same group, if I need push/addToSet two fields or more? For example `{name: Joe, book: A, author: MrX} {name: Joe, book: B, author: MrZ}`

Comment: @mhtyn Yes indeed, try `{
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$name",
            "Books": {
                "$addToSet": { "name": "$name", "book": "$Book", "author": "$Author"}
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: ok, thanks. In my mind I think about spring data framework, it does't allows to "addToSet" more than one argument